# Exit PHP command prompt in Docker container

Tags: php, docker, command-line-interface

Supposedly should be obvious, but neither `exit()` nor `Ctrl-C` work.

[image]

Comment: There is a double quote in the end of your command, so it's waiting for you to close the quote pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @shingo's comment, it was waiting for a double quote

[image]